# Setting Android version code in Ionic 2 / Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-manifest

I'm completely stuck with a crazy issue. I'm not able to publish an update of my app in Google Play store because current version code is **101002**.

Now, I don't understand how that code was generated. In my config.xml I tried using the following versions:

```
1.3
1.3.1
1.3.1.1
```

but every time it generates a version code like:

```
10300
10310
10311
```

that is always lower than the current version code: 101002

I also tried to build using the following command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --versionCode=103020
```

but it doesn't work

I can't manually set the version code of the Manifest file because it's generated by ionic 2 build process. Any idea?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can specify a custom version-code in `config.xml`. Add the following property to the `<widget>` element (the root element): `android-versionCode="101003"`.

This is an example of a full `<widget>` tag with more properties that are probably useful:

```
<widget android-versionCode="100" id="your.bundle.id" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.0.0" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

- `version` is the version displayed in the app stores, can stay the same across different builds
- `android-versionCode` this is used by Google-Play to differentiate between your builds, must always be higher than the previous one
- `CFBundleVersion` is used by iTunesConnect to differentiate your builds, must always be higher than the previous one
- `id` is where you define the bundle identifier of your app, this must always stay the same

Comment: Glad to help! Here is the documentation for `config.xml` if you need to lookup something else: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/

Comment: How it can be done automatically  integrate with CI/CD GItlab pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your project with Android Studio, you can change it in the App-> Manifests-> AndroidManifest.xml folder

[image: screenshot]