# Google Play store rollout issue - how to replace existing live app

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I am new to android development. recently i have uploaded my app to playstore and couldnt download it from there because i faced this issue "your device isnt compatible with this version". on further analysis I could found out that I have used feature "android.hardware.type.watch" along with android.hardware.faketouch, android.hardware.telephony. which is why i could see only watch devices in supported devices list on console (this was mistakenly ignored during rollout).

now to correct this mistake, I have removed watch feature, built apk with incremented version code. I need to replace live app on playstore with newly built apk. I have used 2 methods ( creating release in production and creating beta release )but everytime I am facing below issue
"You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs. I am out of ideas here even after browsing existing posts.
"
Can someone please help? will really appreciate that

Comment: Did you remember to change the `versionCode` in your manifest? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214125/google-play-store-release-issue

Comment: Same things happens me right now,.. do you find solution?