# Error on Rollout : it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting an error when I try to upload the app on the Play Store.

[image]

```
 minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 167
    versionName "2.1.55"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Store Release Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214125/google-play-store-release-issue)

Comment: I have searched but nothing found related this

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed the following line from the Manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```