# You Can't Rollout this Release because It does'nt allow any Existing Users to Upgrade the newly added Apk Play Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I am working on Android Application, after Completion of Project I have Uploaded my App Over `**Google Play**`, the App Successfully Got Live within `**three Days**`. But after that I checked apk it is always showing that the App is not comapatable with any of your deveices like this...
[image: The App is Not Compatable]

I searched this error and in Result I came to Know I should Remove the `Uses-Feature` From Manifest. I remove this from manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    tools:ignore="UnsupportedChromeOsHardware" />
```

I again Uploaded Apk but Now I is Not uploading Apk Over Google Play and Giving Error ...

**You Can't Rollout this Release because It doesn't allow any Existing Users to Upgrade the newly added `Apk` `PlayConsole`**

After First time above Error, I have Created A New Project again and Create App Again But Now Again I try to upload the App It is Giving the Same error of not uploading `apk` Google Play Error.

1. I have Checked the Package Name, it is same as First app
2. Changed Version Code and Name again
3. Created New Project and Done Entire Implementation again.

This is Error Message I Got From The `PlayConsole`
[image: PlayConsole Error]

this is My Gradle File

```
dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:20.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'  //sdp Dimentions
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3' //Vision Lib For Camera Source
implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8' //Permission
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3' //Zxing QR Scanning
implementation 'com.divyanshu.colorseekbar:colorseekbar:1.0.2' //For Color Change
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2' //Country Code Lib

implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.1.0' //Lottie

//Room Database Lib
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5-alpha03"
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

I am Confused What I need to Do Forward..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Store Release Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214125/google-play-store-release-issue)

Comment: I have Aklready checked this Out, But not Fit in My Scnaraio

Comment: have you updated the APK version?

Comment: yes I have Updated, Initially I have Uploading app with Version Code 1 and Version Name 1.0, after 3-4 version Rejected,  Now I have Added Apk With Version Code 12 and version Name 1.1.2