# How to upgrade app bundle or delete previous version app bundle from google console

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, mobile-application, google-developers-console

By mistake, I uploaded to Version code 999999999. to internal testing to google console.
Now I want to upload version code 1.
but I can't do it.
It gives the below error

*Error
You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles.*

is there any way to delete the previous app bundle(99999999) or upload with version code 1 ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately is not possible.
The whole play console does not allow you to push a new version of the app if the Version Code that you are pushing is lower than the one already there.
However since you are using the internal testing you may try to close the track.
On this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214125/google-play-store-release-issue) you will find out that other user had this issue in the past so you can only push a higher number